# Compare files across servers

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, scp, sftp

Once upon a time I remember doing something roughly like this:

```
vimdiff <(scp://some_server/home/user/.zshrc) <(scp://some_server-qa/home/user/.zshrc)
```

(where `some_server` and `some_server-qa` are defined in my `~/.ssh/config` with user and key and so forth, so it's not necessary to include that in the shell).

The problem is that I can't figure out what syntax is needed to make this work, and I haven't been able to find anything by Googling.  I'm sure someone here knows what I'm missing.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vim` does support opening remote files with some URLs, so you can just do:

```
vimdiff scp://some_server{,-qa}/home/user/.zshrc
```

Enter `:h scp` within `vim` for the documentation.

If that support has not been enabled at build time, you can always do instead:

```
vimdiff -R <(ssh some_server cat /home/user/.zshrc) \
           <(ssh some_server-qa cat /home/user/.zshrc)
```

Though you won't be able to modify the remote files.

The `-R` is to make `vim` read-only as a reminder that it's pointless to edit those file (though you could always do: `:w !ssh host 'cat > file'` to send the edited file back (or just `:w !ssh host '>file'` if your login shell on `host` is also `zsh` where `$NULLCMD` happens to be `cat` by default)).

Comment: Aha!  That's why I had recalled both `<(...)` and `scp://`, because I had used both in different situation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As always, Stéphane's answer is masterful.  This is a mere addendum.  If you find this helpful, please upvote his answer too.

I was not able (for whatever reason) to get the `scp://` scheme to work with my systems, but the `sftp://` scheme did work for me:

```
vimdiff sftp://some_server{,-qa}/home/user/.zshrc
```